# Controller test of empty apex:inputText field fails

Tags: apex, visualforce

```
 <tr>
       <td >
           <b><u>SUB/CustomerID(Accountcode) :</u> </b>
           <td colspan="3"> 
           <apex:outputField value="{!Quote__c.Account_Name__r.Account_Code__c  }"/>
           </td>
       </td> 
       <td><apex:inputtext value="{!test}" /></td>
 </tr> 
 <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!Save}"/>
```

controller:

```
public class createorder {
    public List<quote__c> q   {get;set;}
    public List<Quote_line_Item__c> q1 {get;set;}
    public List<Quote_line_Item__c> lineitemdata {get;set;}
    public List<batch__c> modifiedbatch=new List<batch__c>();
    public List<batch__c> finalbatch=new List<batch__c>() ;
    public Date Today { get { return Date.today(); }}
    public List<batch__C> lstbatch {get;set;}
    public String quoteId{get;set;}
    public String imageURL{get;set;}
    public date date1{get;set;}
    public date date2{get;set;}
    public String customerponumber{get;set;}
    public String Carrier{get;set;}
    public String comment{get;set;}
    public String quantity{get;set;}
    public boolean discount{get;set;}
    public decimal price{get;set;}
    public String inputvalue{get;set;}
    public quote__c quote{get;set;}
    public string test{get;set;}

    public createorder(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
       q1 = [select id,Name,Client_P_N__c, final_quantity__c, Final_Discount__c, Requested_Date__c,Final_Price__c from quote_line_item__c WHERE quote1__c = : Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id')];
     }

    public pageReference Save(){
    // q  =[select id,Customer_PO_number__c,Account_name__c,Account_Name__r.Account_Code__c,order_date__c,requested_date__c,comment__c,Carrier__c from Quote__c where id=:Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id')];

    // update q;      
    quoteId=ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().get('id');
    quote__c q=[select id,Account_Code__c from quote__C where id=:quoteid];
    quote__c qu= new quote__c();
    qu.id=q.id;
    qu.Customer_PO_number__c=customerponumber;
    qu.Carrier__c=Carrier;
    qu.order_date__c=date.today();
    qu.comment__c=comment;
    If(test==NULL){
       qu.Test_field__c=test;}
    else{
       qu.test_field__c=qu.Account_Code__c;}

    update qu;
    update q1;
    return null;
    }
```

In this one condition is working every  but not both .

I want that if value not there at text box qu.test_field__c=qu.Account_Code__c;
I want that if value there in textbox qu.tex_field__c=test;

why it is not taking two condition ?

Any other way?

Comment: Try sticking a System.debug(test); above the IF condition and you may get some insight. Should you be using .isEmpty() as a check instead of null for example?

Answer (score 2):

Here's the issue (I remember being frustrated by this myself)

```
<apex:inputText value="{!test}"/>
```

or, for that matter, any `apex:inputText`, VF will always transmit an empty length string to a controller's type=String variable if no value is entered by the user.

You need to test for a zero length string:

```
if (String.isEmpty(test)) ...
```

This is different from `apex:inputField` where empty values on the VF page are sent by VF to the controller as nulls to the corresponding type=string sobject.field

Comment: You can use the String.isEmpty() method since Winter '13. This is the best method.

Comment: it was added Winter '13 and it tests for both null and for 0 length string. Otherwise the .length() test will fail on a null string, so it's a safer and more elegant check

Comment: edited post...appreciate your advancing my learning

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the issue is that you should replace

```
If (test==NULL){
```

with

```
If (String.isEmpty(test)){
```

See String doc http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_string.htm#apex_System_String_isEmpty

As although the controller initially declares the String as null, the setter will set it to an empty string instead which is different.

In working out what is going on here you can use the System.debug methods to work out exactly what your problem is.

You have this

```
If(test==NULL){
       qu.Test_field__c=test;}
    else{
       qu.test_field__c=qu.Account_Code__c;
}
```

and it's not giving you the result you expect... so try this

```
System.debug('** about to perform IF, value of test = ' + test);
If(test==NULL){
        System.debug('** test evaluated to true');
        qu.Test_field__c=test;}
else{
        System.debug('** test evaluated to false');
        qu.test_field__c=qu.Account_Code__c;
}
System.debug('** after performing test, value of test_field is ' + qu.test_field__c);
```

By this kind of approach you can pinpoint the problem for yourself.